# How to convert 500Hz csv data file to wav audio file?

Tags: python, csv, audio, wav

I have a csv file of data, recorded on a data acquisition center with frequency of 500Hz, and I am trying to convert it to wav format. I have trie to Python and simply feed the numbers (as 16bit integers to the `wave` package), and it didn't work. How should I construct a wav file from simply a stream of numbers?

I've tried the following code, which includes normalization, and I set the `dtype` to be float32 so that it would use 32-bit floating-point format according to the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html), it just is not generating any sounds.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
from numpy import *

csv_array = np.loadtxt('trimmed.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float32)

min = np.amin(csv_array)
max = np.amax(csv_array)
med = (max + min) / 2

def f(x):
    return (x - med) * (1 - (-1)) / (max - min)

f = np.vectorize(f)
wav_array = f(csv_array)

scipy.io.wavfile.write('output.wav', 500, csv_array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your sampling rate. Try re-sampling the data to something like 44100 Hz (see code below). I do not know what effects re-sampling will have on your data.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.signal import resample

data = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 500)
data_resampled = resample(data, 44100)

wavfile.write('output.wav', 44100, data_resampled)
```

Try playing around with the `rate` argument in `sipy.io.wavfile.write`. As the rate lowers, the frequency of the sound lowers.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I tried your way and what I got was a blank basically, and no sound at all, I've posted the code as an update to the question, do you mind having a look?

Comment: See my edits. The problem seems to be with your sampling rate.

Comment: Your edits is for creating a randomly generated sound though, my data is from a data acquisition device but I'll try that.

Comment: I didn't know what `csv_array` looked like, so I made my own data for the purpose of the example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also my edits are not only for generating random sound. The edited answer shows you how to resample your data.

Comment: I think your solutions right, and my problem should be too low a frequency to begin with. Thanks!

Comment: the ```output.wav``` can't be read by python.    How to convert vibration waveform data into sound files